# Updating multiple elements in Form Ajax Callback

Tags: ajax, forms

*The Form*

In a Drupal Form I have (amongst other elements):

- Two select lists: Retailers, Products.
- One Table select: Selected Products.
- Two buttons: Add, Remove

*The Functionality*

I want:

- The Products list to be populated when a Retailer is selected in the Retailers select list (this is working)
- A product(s) to be added to the Selected Products table select, Removed from the Products list when it is selected from the Products list and the Add button is pressed. (this is working)
- A product(s) to be removed from the Selected Products table select, Readded from the Products list when it is selected from the Products list and the Add button is pressed. (partially working / partially complete)

*The Problem*

The adding to the Selected product lists works the second time around for another product but removing said product from the Products list doesn't. It is like the Products list is not being rebuilt.

*The Code*

```
function spraydo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // Adds the retailer select box to the Add / Edit Product form
    if ($form_id === "commerce_product_ui_product_form") {
        $retailer_selected_id = isset ( $form_state ['values'] ['retailers'] ) ? $form_state ['values'] ['retailers'] : '';
        $retailer_product_selected_id = isset ( $form_state ['values'] ['retailer_products'] ) ? $form_state ['values'] ['retailer_products'] : '';

        if (empty ( $form_state ['selected_products'] )) {
            $form_state ['selected_products'] = array ();
        }

        $form ['retailers'] = array (
                '#title' => t ( 'Retailers' ),
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#multiple' => 'true',
                '#prefix' => '<div id="retailers-dropdown">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>',
                '#options' => spraydo_get_retailer_options (),
                '#ajax' => array (
                        'callback' => 'spraydo_retailer_products_callback',
                        'wrapper' => 'products-dropdown'
                )
        );

        $form ['retailer_products'] = array (
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#title' => t ( 'Products' ),
                '#multiple' => 'true',
                '#options' => spraydo_get_retailer_products_options ( $retailer_selected_id, $form_state ),
                '#prefix' => '<div id="products-dropdown">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>',
                '#default_value' => ''
        );

        $form ['add_product'] = array (
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t ( 'Add' ),
                '#submit' => array (
                        'spraydo_add_product'
                ),
                '#ajax' => array (
                        'callback' => 'spraydo_products_selected_callback',
                        'wrapper' => 'products-selected-dropdown'
                )
        );

        $form ['remove_product'] = array (
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t ( 'Remove' ),
                '#submit' => array (
                        'spraydo_remove_product'
                ),
                '#ajax' => array (
                        'callback' => 'spraydo_products_selected_callback',
                        'wrapper' => 'products-selected-dropdown'
                )
        );

        $header = array (
                'retailer' => t ( 'Retailer' ),
                'product' => t ( 'Product' )
        );

        $form ['products_selected'] = array (
                '#type' => 'tableselect',
                '#title' => t ( 'Selected Products' ),
                '#prefix' => '<div id="products-selected-dropdown">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>',
                '#header' => $header,
                '#options' => $form_state ['selected_products'],
                '#empty' => t ( 'No content available.' )
        );
    }
}

    function spraydo_get_retailer_options() {
    global $user;
    $uid = $user->uid;
    $retailer_array = array ();
    $result = db_query ( 'SELECT u.uid, u.name FROM {users} u WHERE u.uid IN (SELECT ur.requester_id from {user_relationships} ur WHERE ur.requestee_id = :requestee_id)', array (
            ':requestee_id' => $uid
    ) );
    if ($result->rowCount () > 0) {
        foreach ( $result as $record ) {
            $key = $record->uid;
            $value = $record->name;
            $retailer_array [$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $retailer_array;
}

    function spraydo_retailer_products_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form ['retailer_products'];
}

    function spraydo_get_retailer_products_options($key = '', $form_state) {
    $already_selected = '';
    foreach ( $form_state ['selected_products'] as $item ) {
        $already_selected .= $item ['product'];
        $already_selected .= ',';
    }
    $already_selected = rtrim ( $already_selected, ',' );
    $result = db_query ( 'SELECT p.product_id, p.title FROM {commerce_product} p WHERE p.uid = :user_id and p.title NOT IN (:product_titles)', array (
            ':user_id' => $key,
            ':product_titles' => $already_selected 
    ) );
    $products_array = array ();
    if ($result->rowCount () > 0) {
        foreach ( $result as $record ) {
            $key = $record->product_id;
            $value = $record->title;
            $products_array [$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $products_array;
}

    function spraydo_products_selected_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return array (
            '#type' => 'ajax',
            '#commands' => array (
                    ajax_command_replace ( "#products-dropdown", render ( $form ['retailer_products'] ) ),
                    ajax_command_replace ( "#products-selected-dropdown", render ( $form ['products_selected'] ) ) 
            ) 
    );
}

function spraydo_add_product($form, &$form_state) {
    $retailer_selected_id = isset ( $form_state ['values'] ['retailers'] ) ? $form_state ['values'] ['retailers'] : '';
    $retailer_products_selected_id = isset ( $form_state ['values'] ['retailer_products'] ) ? $form_state ['values'] ['retailer_products'] : '';

    if (! empty ( $retailer_selected_id ) && ! empty ( $retailer_products_selected_id )) {
        $retailer_name_result = db_query ( 'SELECT u.name FROM {users} u WHERE u.uid = :uid', array (
                ':uid' => reset ( $retailer_selected_id ) 
        ) );
        $retailer_name = '';
        foreach ( $retailer_name_result as $record ) {
            $retailer_name = $record->name;
        }
        $product_names_result = db_query ( 'SELECT p.product_id, p.title FROM {commerce_product} p WHERE p.product_id = :pid', array (
                ':pid' => reset ( $retailer_products_selected_id ) 
        ) );
        foreach ( $product_names_result as $record ) {
            $form_state ['selected_products'] [$record->product_id] = array (
                    'retailer' => $retailer_name,
                    'product' => $record->title 
            );
        }
    }
    $form_state ['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function spraydo_remove_product($form, &$form_state) {
    foreach ( $form_state ['values'] ['products_selected'] as $record ) {
        unset ( $form_state ['selected_products'] [$record] );
        $form_state ['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```